# Database other than PSQL for pact broker

Tags: pact, pact-broker

Can we use SQL server as the database for pact broker? I don't see any documentation related to that anywhere. The problem is that I don't have PostgreSQL at my workplace and I was asked to evaluate whether SQL server serves the purpose. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We currently test and support PostgreSQL and MySQL. I'm sorry but SQL server has not been tested and we can't provide any guarantees.

There are services like Pactflow [1] that you could look to offload the admin burden to if you were able to go with a a SaaS product.

1. https://pactflow.io